# How to Dynamically parse xml using xslt to detect integers and convert that to decimal? I have schema also in the xml file I need that to be deleted

Tags: xml, parsing, xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RS xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset">
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:saw-sql="urn:saw-sql" targetNamespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset">
    <xsd:complexType name="R">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="C0" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="varchar" saw-sql:displayFormula="&quot;Inventory Org&quot;.&quot;Inventory Org Name&quot;" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:tableHeading="Replenishments_Fact" saw-sql:columnHeading="Source Organization" saw-sql:columnID="c7"/>
            <xsd:element name="C1" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="varchar" saw-sql:displayFormula="&quot;Item Inventory Product&quot;.&quot;Product Number&quot;" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:tableHeading="Item" saw-sql:columnHeading="Kanban Item" saw-sql:columnID="c1"/>
            <xsd:element name="C2" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="varchar" saw-sql:displayFormula="&quot;Kanban Cards&quot;.&quot;Kanban Card Number&quot;" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:tableHeading="Kanban Card" saw-sql:columnHeading="Card Number" saw-sql:columnID="c0"/>
            <xsd:element name="C3" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="integer" saw-sql:displayFormula="&quot;Fact - Kanban Card Activity&quot;.&quot;# of Replenishment Cycles&quot;" saw-sql:aggregationRule="sum" saw-sql:aggregationType="agg" saw-sql:tableHeading="Replenishments_Fact" saw-sql:columnHeading="Replenishment Cycle" saw-sql:columnID="c8"/>
            <xsd:element name="C4" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="varchar" saw-sql:displayFormula="&quot;Storage Location&quot;.&quot;Subinventory Location&quot;" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:tableHeading="Replenishments_Fact" saw-sql:columnHeading="Subinventory" saw-sql:columnID="c2"/>
            <xsd:element name="C5" type="xsd:dateTime" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="timestamp" saw-sql:displayFormula="&quot;Time&quot;.&quot;Date&quot;" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:tableHeading="Replenishments_Fact" saw-sql:columnHeading="Activity Date" saw-sql:columnID="c3"/>
            <xsd:element name="C6" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="varchar" saw-sql:displayFormula="&quot;Kanban Codes&quot;.&quot;Kanban Card Status&quot;" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:tableHeading="Replenishments_Fact" saw-sql:columnHeading="Card Status" saw-sql:columnID="c4"/>
            <xsd:element name="C7" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="varchar" saw-sql:displayFormula="&quot;Kanban Codes&quot;.&quot;Kanban Source Type&quot;" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:tableHeading="Replenishments_Fact" saw-sql:columnHeading="Supply Type" saw-sql:columnID="c5"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
<R>
    <C0>Vision Operations</C0>
    <C1>f_item</C1>
    <C2>1</C2>
    <C3>4</C3>
    <C4>Stores</C4>
    <C5>2011-10-13T00:00:00</C5>
    <C6>Active</C6>
    <C7>Supplier</C7>
</R>
<R>
    <C0>SManufacturing</C0>
    <C1>KB18759</C1>
    <C2>100</C2>
    <C3>2</C3>
    <C4>Stores</C4>
    <C5>1999-02-03T00:00:00</C5>
    <C6>Active</C6>
    <C7>Supplier</C7>
</R>
```

and I want the result like this, with integers being converted to decimals and schema has been removed.
The parsing should be dynamic as the rows are ,ore. Please help me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <RS xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset"> 
<R>
<C0>Vision Operations</C0>
<C1>f_item</C1>
<C2>1.00000</C2>
<C3>4.00000</C3>
<C4>Stores</C4>
<C5>2011-10-13T00:00:00</C5>
<C6>Active</C6>
<C7>Supplier</C7>
</R>
<R>
<C0>Seattle Manufacturing</C0> 
<C1>KB18759</C1>
 <C2>100.00000</C2>
<C3>2.00000</C3>
<C4>Stores</C4>
<C5>1999-02-03T00:00:00</C5>
<C6>Active</C6>
<C7>Supplier</C7>
</R>
 </RS>
```

Above is the final output required. with all the values being parsed and integers being converted to decimals

Comment: Where are you facing the trouble, show some code of what you have already tried and where you are stuck

Comment: @Ani It worked . with Michae'l suggestion which is below this, with a bit change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a stylesheet with:

an identity template that copies elements by default

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

a template that deletes the schema element

```
<xsl:template match="*:schema"/>
```

a template that converts integers to decimal notation

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(*)][translate(., '0123456789', '') = '']">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(number(.), '0.00000')"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

All the above is XSLT 1.0. The third template could be made a bit nicer with XSLT 2.0:

`match="*[. castable as xs:integer]"`.

Comment: strings are not at all getting displayed. NaN is appearing

Comment: strings are not at all getting displayed. NaN is appearing
`<C0>NaN</C0>'
'<C1>NaN</C1>'

Comment: I tested my code and it works correctly. I don't know what you did wrong. The [not(*)] predicate is not essential to this example but it's logically more correct to ensure that this template rule is only applied to elements that have no element children.

Comment: Hi @Michael Kay , Thanks for the help. The logic is failing if there are no Strings in the input file  
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <rowset>
      <Row>
       <Column0>0</Column0>
       <Column1>1381</Column1>
    <Column2>9460</Column2>
    <Column3>121</Column3>
    <Column4>130253</Column4>
    <Column5>1885.4</Column5>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Column0>0</Column0>
    <Column1>1381</Column1>
    <Column2>9460</Column2>
    <Column3>2121</Column3>
    <Column4>130253</Column4>
    <Column5>2228.2</Column5>
  </Row>
  </rowset>

Comment: That's why the not(*) condition is necessary.

Comment: Got it @Michael Thanks. Now I want to get this as a table in html. But  number of columns vary from record to record. The table header should be also printed based on number of columns in that record. What would be the xslt for this.?

Comment: That sounds like a completely different question. Start a new thread.

Comment: @Micheal Thanks I did. But there is one more issue, the decimal formatting upto 5 digits which you sugested now will not work to format a number which is some thing like this. -0.4567825252527 . I want to format this number as well. The required ouput is -0.45678. How to go with that

Comment: Please don't keep changing the question. If you have another problem, start another thread. I answered the question you originally asked.